# Serve javascript file from public folder with express js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a partial for hooking up scripts. It links scripts like the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

There is only one javascript script that I made myself in that partial. I am unable to serve it. This is what I'm attempting:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/myjavascript.js>"></script>
```

where myjavascript.js belongs to javascripts which belongs to public. The error here is 404 not found.

Please note that scripts from an online source work fine and are being served in the same partial. I can assure you that my spelling is correct and that the file exists at that src location. What am I doing wrong?

My error message attaches a strange extension too. Not sure if that's a clue or not.

[image]

Comment: You will have to show us what node.js/express code you are using to serve public files.  Questions about code MUST include the relevant code.  And, in case you didn't know, node.js serves NO files by default.  So, if you want it to serve a specific Javascript file or a directory of files, you have to add code to your server to do that.  Static files in are often served in Express with `app.use(express.static(...))` where you fill in appropriate parameters to the `.static()` method.

Comment: This is why I mentioned that other scripts from the same partial ARE being served.

Comment: OK, it looks like you just have a simple typo in your script tag.  If that is indeed the issue, you should probably just delete this question as it is of little use to those who come after.  This question should be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/myjavascript.js>"></script>
                                this '>' does not belong here --^
```

The corrected code would be

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/myjavascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks that was it sry my bad

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

possibly one too many "/" and one too many ">"